# Permission denied on aio-max-nr file

Tags: linux, proc, sysctl

I would like to edit the file aio-max-nr:

```
root@node:~# echo 65536 > /proc/sys/fs/aio-max-nr
-su: /proc/sys/fs/aio-max-nr: Permission denied
```

Knowing that :

```
root@node:~# ls -lrth /proc/sys/fs/aio-max-nr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov 22 17:02 /proc/sys/fs/aio-max-nr
```

I don't understand why !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you're running in a Linux-on-Linux soft virtualization environment such as LXC or OpenVZ where all virtual machines run above the same instance of the Linux kernel. In this kind of environment, kernel parameters (such as the sysctl parameters that you can set via `/proc/sys`) apply to every virtual machine. Therefore only root in the host environment can modify those parameters, root in a virtual machine cannot.

If you need to allow more I/O requests, you'll need to ask your VPS provider. But they'll probably say no, because if 65536 isn't enough for you, you should probably be on a bigger, non-virtualized setup where you aren't sharing I/O.

Comment: Right, my host runs OpenVZ as container. I don't see the advantage of using a VPS then ! I had a problem with mysql Innodb installation that demand more IO apparently.